# Selectively add UITextView to A UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How do I add a UITextField to only eight tableview cells in a table with only one section...

Comment: You should really post your questions with a much more informative title so people can know if they can help before clicking on the question - or more likely people who can answer your question will just skip over it.

Comment: `iphone programming` is so vague a title that I was actually surprised to find a question about table view cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(indexPath.row < 8)
    {
                    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 100.0f)];
                    [[cell contentView] textView];
}
```

to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method in your implementation file

Answer (score 0):

1) How many cells is going to be in your tableview?
2) Do you need to position it in any way?
3) What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: just like contactslist program

Answer (score 0):

Insid of 'cellForRow:atIndexPath', just add some 'if{}else{}' code.

If all of your cells are in one section, you want to use '[indexPath row]' to differentiate between them.